# EC2 instance won't recognize IAM role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I'm trying to download ECR images on my EC2 instance without having to provide a credentials file. So I created a role with the policy `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly` and attached to my running instance. However, when I run `aws ecr describe-repositories --region us-east-2`, I get the following error:

> Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".

I'm not sure if attaching the role to the instance is sufficient, but I already tried to restart the instance and it still doesn't work.

Here's some screenshots from the AWS Console that may help find the problem:

- [The role with the policy attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dPCZ.png);
- [The instance with the role attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxryK.png);
- [The error I get when trying to read from ECR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5Pv3.png).

Comment: are you sure your aws cli is configured correctly?

Comment: @c4f4t0r: There was no configuration file (I didn't created one and the instances comes without one). I launched a new instance and it worked. I compared the versions and it was the same, but they both was at version 1. I upgraded AWS cli on the old machine and it worked, no idea why. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling/upgrading AWS cli made it work.

The AWS cli was at version 1, after upgrading to version 2 it worked. Before that, I launched a new EC2 instance (Amazon Linux 2) with the attached role and it worked at AWS cli version 1, the exact same of the old machine.